# UITableViewCell are transparent when UITableView is transparent

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a TableView as a subview of an UIViewController, presented modally. The TableView has a clear background. When I set the cells background to white, cells appears transparent but when color is set to Red everything is ok.

What's going on ?

Comment: Is your ViewController's background white?

Comment: No it's transparent to.

Comment: can you provide screenshots? I'm not seeing how one color would work, and another one would not